# Android Application for Alexa: Not able to fetch custom skills

Tags: alexa-voice-service

I am creating an android application for Alexa where I should be able to invoke my custom skills after adding a mic on the android app. By following the document [given here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/login-with-amazon/docs/install_sdk_android.html), I am able to login into amazon account but all I am able to get is user name, email address and postal address using the sample application provided by amazon.

Can someone guide me to those specific APIs from where I can fetch all my skills in to my android application?

Many Thanks